# Fastest/easiest way to build a WebKit based Windows application?

Tags: windows, webkit, desktop-application, growl

I am a web developer. I don't know how to build native Windows applications. I recently built a Mac desktop application (using MacRuby) which is a WebKit wrapper around one of my web applications. I'd like to do the same thing for Windows (preferably in Ruby, but whatever is easiest).

Since this is not the core of the application, I'd rather not spend a lot of time trying to build and maintain it. I just need a Windows application that can:

- Open a specific website on application launch using an embedded WebKit WebView
- Trigger Growl notifications via JavaScript (with some sort of named bridge)

What is the easiest, fastest, cleanest way to do this?

**Update:** So far I've come across some frameworks like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) and [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/). I don't know how these frameworks compare to other options available, so if you have any opinions or advice, I would appreciate it.

Comment: It isn't easy, not clean and *definitely* not fast.  You won't appreciate that until you try it yourself.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is I don't know the first thing about writing Windows apps and could use some advice.

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://appjs.org/ it's built with NodeJS at its core! And it uses chromium webkit at it's core :D

Comment: That looks pretty cool, but I can't tell if it allows you to package your app for distribution. Do you know if you can do that with appjs?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is a very old question, but if you are still interested...

I'd recommend Qt.  There are some very good books available with a lot of boilerplate code and wizard-type tools.  You will be able to find example code demonstrating the embedded Webkit that you can modify to suit your needs.  It is free and redistribution is free (last I knew).  You won't have to know anything about native Windows development, nor even use any native Windows dev tools.

Good luck!